# Issue with finding a rival in a Django web page

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django web application that allows users to register teams, add players to those teams, and then find a rival team. However, I am experiencing an issue when users click the "Find Rival" button, as the system does not seem to find an appropriate rival team and leaves the user waiting.

Here's an overview of the web page structure:

The homepage (index.html) allows users to register a team by entering their details and location.
In the create_players.html page, users can register players for the previously created team.
After registering the players, users can click the "Find Rival" button to find a rival team.
The issue seems to be related to the following code:

The JavaScript function findRival() in the create_players.html template is responsible for finding a rival. When the "Find Rival" button is clicked, this function sends a POST request to the /find_rival/ route on the Django server.
Potential causes of the issue include the findRival() function not sending the team data to the Django server correctly, the find_rival view on the Django server not properly processing the received data and/or not returning the rival information in the expected format, and the JavaScript code in the findRival() function not properly processing the server response.
I would appreciate any help in identifying and resolving the issue. Please find the relevant code snippets below:

The findRival() function in the create_players.html template
The find_rival view on the Django server, which is responsible for processing the POST request and finding a suitable rival.
Please let me know if you need any additional information or clarification on the expected behavior of the "Find Rival" functionality. Thank you!

```
    ((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 teams]$ cat forms.py
    from django import forms
    from .models import Team, Player
    
    class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
        num_players = forms.IntegerField(label='Número de jugadores', min_value=2, max_value=10)
    
        class Meta:
            model = Team
            fields = ('name', 'num_players', 'whatsapp_number',)
            labels = {
                'name': 'Nombre',
                'whatsapp_number': 'Número de Whatsapp',
            }
    
    class PlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
        name = forms.CharField(label='Nombre de tu jugador #', required=True)
        speed = forms.IntegerField(label='Velocidad', min_value=1, max_value=10, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'range'}))
        control = forms.IntegerField(label='Control', min_value=1, max_value=10, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'range'}))
        shot = forms.IntegerField(label='Disparo', min_value=1, max_value=10, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'range'}))
        defense = forms.IntegerField(label='Defensa', min_value=1, max_value=10, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'range'}))
        attack = forms.IntegerField(label='Ataque', min_value=1, max_value=10, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'range'}))
    
        class Meta:
            model = Player
            fields = ('name', 'speed', 'control', 'shot', 'defense', 'attack')((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 teams]$ cat models.py
    from django.db import models
    
    class Team(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        num_players = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
        longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
        whatsapp_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    
    
    class Player(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        speed = models.IntegerField()
        control = models.IntegerField()
        shot = models.IntegerField()
        defense = models.IntegerField()
        attack = models.IntegerField()
```

```
    ((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 teams]$ cat team_matching.py
    from geopy.distance import great_circle
    from .models import Team, Player
    import time
    
    def find_nearby_team(team, max_distance=30, timeout=30):
        nearby_teams = Team.objects.exclude(id=team.id).filter(num_players=team.num_players)
    
        team_players = Player.objects.filter(team=team)
        team_avg_skill = sum([p.speed + p.control + p.shot + p.defense + p.attack for p in team_players]) / len(team_players)
    
        best_rival = None
        best_skill_difference = float('inf')
        teams_analyzed = 0
    
        start_time = time.monotonic()  # Usa time.monotonic() en lugar de time.time()
    
        for nearby_team in nearby_teams:
            if time.monotonic() - start_time > timeout:  # Usa time.monotonic() en lugar de time.time()
                print("Se alcanzó el tiempo límite.")
                break
    
            team_coords = (team.latitude, team.longitude)
            nearby_team_coords = (nearby_team.latitude, nearby_team.longitude)
    
            # Filtra los equipos en función de la distancia máxima
            if great_circle(team_coords, nearby_team_coords).km <= max_distance:
                teams_analyzed += 1
                print(f"Equipo analizado: {nearby_team}")
    
                rival_players = Player.objects.filter(team=nearby_team)
                rival_avg_skill = sum([p.speed + p.control + p.shot + p.defense + p.attack for p in rival_players]) / len(rival_players)
    
                skill_difference = abs(team_avg_skill - rival_avg_skill)
    
                if skill_difference < best_skill_difference and skill_difference < team_avg_skill * 0.5:
                    best_skill_difference = skill_difference
                    best_rival = nearby_team
    
        return best_rival, teams_analyzed
```

```
    ((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 teams]$ cat utils.py
    from geopy.distance import distance
    from .models import Team
    
    def find_nearby_team(team, max_distance):
        nearby_teams = Team.objects.exclude(id=team.id)
        for nearby_team in nearby_teams:
            team_coords = (team.latitude, team.longitude)
            nearby_team_coords = (nearby_team.latitude, nearby_team.longitude)
            if distance(team_coords, nearby_team_coords).km <= max_distance:
                return nearby_team
        return None
```

````
    ((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 teams]$ cat urls.py
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    from django.views.generic import RedirectView
    from django.contrib import messages
    from .views import index, create_players, list_teams, delete_all_teams, rival_details, console_log
    
    
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='home'),
        path('create_players/<int:team_id>/', views.create_players, name='create_players'),
        path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/images/favicon.ico', permanent=True)),
        path('list_teams/', views.list_teams, name='list_teams'),
        path('delete_all_teams/', views.delete_all_teams, name='delete_all_teams'),
        path('rival_details/<int:team_id>/<int:rival_id>/', views.rival_details, name='rival_details'),
        path('console_log/', views.console_log, name='console_log'),
        path('find_rival/', views.find_rival, name='find_rival')

,```
````

```
((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 teams]$ cat views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import Team, Player
from .forms import TeamForm, PlayerForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.forms import formset_factory
from geopy.distance import distance
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .team_matching import find_nearby_team
from .utils import find_nearby_team
import time
import logging
from django.http import HttpResponseNotAllowed
from django.urls import reverse

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def find_rival(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            team_id = int(request.POST.get('team_id'))
            team = Team.objects.get(id=team_id)
            logger.debug("Iniciando la búsqueda de rival para el equipo %s...", team)
            best_rival, teams_analyzed = find_nearby_team(team, max_distance=10, timeout=30)
            if best_rival is not None:
                logger.debug("Rival encontrado: %s", best_rival)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('rival_details', args=[team_id, best_rival.id]))
            else:
                logger.warning("No se encontró ningún rival cercano para el equipo %s", team)
                return render(request, 'teams/list_teams.html', {'error': 'No se encontró ningún rival cercano'})
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception("Error en find_rival: %s", e)
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])

def console_log(request):
    message = request.GET.get('message', '')
    print(f"DEBUG: {message}")
    return HttpResponse("Logged.")

def rival_details(request, team_id, rival_id):
    try:
        team = Team.objects.get(id=team_id)
        max_distance = 30  # Cambia el valor a 30 km
        rival, teams_analyzed = find_nearby_team(team, max_distance)

        context = {
            'team': team,
            'rival': rival
        }
        return render(request, 'teams/rival_details.html', context)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Error en rival_details: %s", e)
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)



def delete_all_teams(request):
    Team.objects.all().delete()
    return HttpResponse("Todos los equipos han sido eliminados.")


def list_teams(request):
    teams = Team.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'teams/list_teams.html', {'teams': teams})



def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TeamForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            team = form.save(commit=False)
            team.latitude = request.POST.get('latitude')
            team.longitude = request.POST.get('longitude')
            team.save()
            return redirect('create_players', team_id=team.id)
    else:
        form = TeamForm()
        latitude = request.GET.get('latitude', None)
        longitude = request.GET.get('longitude', None)

    return render(request, 'teams/index.html', {'form': form, 'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude})


def register_team(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TeamForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            team = form.save(commit=False)
            team.latitude = request.POST.get('latitude')
            team.longitude = request.POST.get('longitude')
            team.save()
            return redirect('create_players', team_id=team.id)
    else:
        form = TeamForm()
        latitude = request.GET.get('latitude', None)
        longitude = request.GET.get('longitude', None)

    return render(request, 'teams/register_team.html', {'form': form, 'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude})


def create_players(request, team_id):
    team = Team.objects.get(id=team_id)
    if not team_id:
        return redirect('home')

    PlayerFormSet = formset_factory(PlayerForm, extra=team.num_players, max_num=team.num_players)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = PlayerFormSet(request.POST, prefix='player')
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                player = form.save(commit=False)
                player.team = team
                player.save()
            return redirect('find_rival', team_id=team_id)
    else:
        formset = PlayerFormSet(prefix='player')

    return render(request, 'teams/create_players.html', {'formset': formset, 'team': team})




def create_team(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TeamForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            team = form.save(commit=False)
            team.latitude = float(request.POST.get('latitude', 0))
            team.longitude = float(request.POST.get('longitude', 0))
            team.save()
            return redirect('create_players', team_id=team.id)
    else:
        form = TeamForm()
    return render(request, 'teams/create_team.html', {'form': form})
```

````
Templates

    ```
    ((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 teams]$ cd templates/
    ((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 templates]$ ls
    teams
    ((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 templates]$ cd teams/
    ((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 teams]$ ls
    base.html  create_players.html  index.html  list_teams.html  register_team.html  rival_details.html
    ((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 teams]$ cat index.html
    {% extends 'teams/base.html' %}
    
    {% block content %}
        <!-- Contenedor principal -->
        <div class="container">
    
            <!-- Campo de fútbol -->
            <div class="field">
                <!-- Efecto de entrada al campo de fútbol -->
            </div>
    
            <h2>Registrar equipo</h2>
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="latitude">
                <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude">
                <button type="button" onclick="getLocation()">Inscribe a tu equipo</button>
            </form>
    
            <!-- Contenido dinámico para registrar equipo y jugadores -->
            <div id="team-registration" class="hidden">
                <!-- Aquí se cargará el contenido dinámico para registrar el equipo y jugadores -->
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
        <!-- Script para obtener ubicación actual del usuario -->
        <script>
            function getLocation() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                        document.getElementById("latitude").value = position.coords.latitude;
                        document.getElementById("longitude").value = position.coords.longitude;
                        document.querySelector("form").submit();
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("La geolocalización no está disponible en su navegador.");
                }
            }
        </script>
    {% endblock %}

    ((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 teams]$ cat create_players.html
    {% extends 'teams/base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block content %}
        <h2>Registrar jugadores para el equipo: {{ team.name }}</h2>
        <form method="post" id="create-players-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ formset.management_form }}
            {% for form in formset %}
                <div class="player-form">
                    <h4>¿Cómo se siente el día de hoy este jugador?</h4>
                    {{ form.name.label_tag }} {{ form.name }}
                    {{ form.speed.label_tag }} {{ form.speed }}
                    {{ form.control.label_tag }} {{ form.control }}
                    {{ form.shot.label_tag }} {{ form.shot }}
                    {{ form.defense.label_tag }} {{ form.defense }}
                    {{ form.attack.label_tag }} {{ form.attack }}
                </div>
                <br>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="hidden" id="team_id" value="{{ team.id }}">  <!-- Añade esta línea -->
            <button type="button" id="search-rival-btn" onclick="findRival()">Buscar rival</button>
        </form>
    
        <!-- Añade esto en el archivo HTML donde se busca el rival -->
        <div id="finding-rival-message" style="display:none;">
            Buscando rival... <span id="search-status">Iniciando búsqueda</span> | Rivales analizados: <span id="rival-counter">0</span>
        </div>
    
    {% endblock %}
    
    
    {% block extra_js %}
        <script>
            let searchStartTime;
            let rivalCounter = 0;
            const searchDuration = 30 * 1000; // 30 segundos en milisegundos
            const rivalDetailsBaseUrl = `{% url 'rival_details' team_id=team.id rival_id=0 %}`.slice(0, -1); // Elimina el último carácter (0) de la URL
            const teamId = {{ team.id }}; // Agrega esta línea para obtener el valor de teamId
    
            function getCookie(name) {
                let cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cookieValue;
            }
    
            function findRival() {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "/find_rival/", true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie("csrftoken"));
    
                // Muestra el mensaje de "buscando rival..."
                document.getElementById("finding-rival-message").style.display = "block";
    
                if (!searchStartTime) {
                    searchStartTime = new Date().getTime();
                }
    
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                        let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        console.log('Respuesta recibida:', response);
    
                        // Actualiza el contador de equipos analizados
                        rivalCounter = response.teams_analyzed;
                        document.getElementById("rival-counter").textContent = rivalCounter;
    
                        if (response.rival_id === null) {
                            let currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                            if (currentTime - searchStartTime < searchDuration) {
                                // Actualiza el mensaje de búsqueda
                                document.getElementById("search-status").textContent = "Intentando nuevamente...";
    
                                // Si no se encuentra rival y no han pasado 30 segundos, vuelve a intentar en 10 segundos
                                console.log('No se encontró rival, intentando nuevamente en 10 segundos...');
                                setTimeout(findRival, 10000);
                            } else {
                                // Oculta el mensaje de "buscando rival..."
                                document.getElementById("finding-rival-message").style.display = "none";
                                alert('No se encontró rival después de 30 segundos. Intente nuevamente más tarde.');
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Oculta el mensaje de "buscando rival..."
                            document.getElementById("finding-rival-message").style.display = "none";
                            window.location.href = rivalDetailsBaseUrl + response.rival_id;
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log('Estado de la solicitud:', xhr.readyState, 'Código de estado:', xhr.status);
                    }
                };
    
                xhr.open('POST', '{% url "find_rival" %}', true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', getCookie("csrftoken"));
                xhr.send('team_id=' + teamId);
            }
        </script>
    {% endblock %}
    
    
    ((MICRO/IA:3.8)) [hrkagwif@bh8932 teams]$ cat rival_details.html
    {% extends 'teams/base.html' %}
    
    {% block content %}
        <div class="team-details">
            <h2>{{ team.name }}</h2>
            <p>Número de jugadores: {{ team.num_players }}</p>
            <p>
                Contacto de WhatsApp:
                <a href="https://wa.me/{{ team.whatsapp_number }}" target="_blank">
                    {{ team.whatsapp_number }}
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    
        <h2>VS</h2>
    
        <div class="rival-details">
            <h2>{{ rival.name }}</h2>
            <p>Número de jugadores: {{ rival.num_players }}</p>
            <p>
                Contacto de WhatsApp:
                <a href="https://wa.me/{{ rival.whatsapp_number }}" target="_blank">
                    {{ rival.whatsapp_number }}
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
````

I implemented the "Find Rival" functionality in my Django web application, which should allow users to find a suitable rival team after registering their own team and players. I expected that when users click the "Find Rival" button, the system would locate an appropriate rival team and display it to the user.

However, when I tested the feature, the system did not seem to find a rival team as expected. Instead, the user was left waiting without any response or indication of a rival team being found. I am trying to identify the root cause of this issue and resolve it so that the "Find Rival" feature works as intended.

Comment: You have two `xhr.open('P...` blocks in your code. One on top, the other on the bottom of the function. Remove the first block and move the second block with `xhr.send('team_...` to the top. In the first block, which you should remove, you miss to send the `team_id`. Your `find_rival` view will never receive a team_id.

Comment: Marco is probably right and the answer could just as easily be found by enabling debugging on the site, there is no traceback here for us to see the error.